# Find the set of accumulation points of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the general approach when you want to find the set of accumulation points of $A$? I'm never sure how to approach these problems. We know that $x$ is an accumulation point of a set $S$ iff there exists a sequence $(s_n)$ of points in $S\setminus\{x\}$ such that $(s_n)$ converges to $x.$

And is my solution below correct?

For $A = \{\frac{n!}{3^n}, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then $A' = \{\infty\}$

and for $A = \{(0,1)\ \setminus \mathbb{Q}\}$, then  $A' =[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Thank you!

Comment: For $(0,1)\setminus\Bbb Q$, are rational points in $(0,1)$ not limit points of $A$? Any neighbourhood of the rational point will contain infinitely many irrational points in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Your first one is correct in the extended reals; in $\Bbb R$ the set of limit points is $\varnothing$.

Comment: So for $(0,1)∖Q$ , A' is still =$ [0,1]$? @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Yes. That is true.